# How to cast to a control found on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, casting, findcontrol

Working on ASP.NET app, my project need to find control from page ,use bellow syntax to find control from a page:

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
{
    Control FoundCtl = new Control();
    if (Root.ID == Id)
        return Root;

    foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
    {
        if (FoundCtl != null && FoundCtl.ID == Id)
        {
            
            Type ty = FoundCtl.GetType();
            var r = FoundCtl as ty; 
            
            //var r = FoundCtl as  Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox;   
        }

        FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);

        //if (FoundCtl != null)
        //    return FoundCtl;
    }

    return FoundCtl;
}
```

For retrieve  control value from   the control need to cast.
For cast use bellow syntax

```
FoundCtl as TextBox;
```

Is it possible to cast find control as bellow

```
Type ty = FoundCtl.GetType();
var r = FoundCtl as ty;
```

Comment: You can't convert System.Object/Web.Control to something using target's own information. Type in cast should be specified in sour code, the same as generic constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in such way. All cast operators is not work with variable of type System.Type . Moreover, if you want to work with this control in runtime with reflection, you can use reflection methods to work with it (such as `PropertyInfo.SetValue` etc). 
But usually you exatly know what type is of concrete control. Why do you want to cast in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The most proper way is the following:

```
TextBox textBox = FindControl("name") as TextBox;
if (textBox != null)
{
    // use it
}
```

Why doesn't it work for you?

---

Also you can use an extension method to find controls of given type recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControls(this Control control)
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<Control>() : Enumerable.Empty<Control>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Usage:

```
var textBoxex = this.GetChildControls<TextBox>();
```

Comment: abatishchev,thanks for reply ,I know how to cast a control ,hope you see in my question description ,want to cast control on run time,in my project need to find several time so many controls, so decide to make a common method which   find a control  and return me a specific control object ,suppose if I send a control id which type=dropdown  then  it’s return me this control specific dropdown object

Comment: @shamim: Do you have a control to find as a `System.Type`? Then use [IsAssignableFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

Comment: But more probably you may want to use compile-type generic: `Controls.OfType<T> where T : Control`, i.e. `FindControl<TextBox>(id)`.